# The command used to find out space utilized by java in linux?

Tags: linux

The command used to find out space utilized by java  in linux?

Comment: define the word space. disk space?

Comment: space: the final frontier! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense checking the memory usage using OS depended tools. The memory of the "base" JVM might be even fix. With base meaning something like: Everything except the loaded classes and applied memory switches. The internal memory management in the JVM is bit complicated and i would recommend reading [Memory Management in the Java HotSpot Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/whitepapers/memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf). Better use tools like jvisualvm or jconsole, which are both distributed with the JDK. jconsole even shows the committed physical memory in the tab "VM Summary". Interpreting the memory output of /bin/ps [might a bit confusing](http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html), so i would not recommend it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ps | grep java` or `top`.

Comment: or `top` + press `m` - java will always be the first row without fail :)

Comment: @Kimvais: On my computer, the top row is...VirtualBox. :-P